# I want some element is not collapse when use navbar-collapse BS4

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

Because of my bad english so, forgive me.

I have this navbar at https://jsfiddle.net/3vmajng0/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sb-navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="ml-1">Start Bootstrap</span>
    </a>
        <div class="avatar-image">
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto pt-3 pt-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/item">Product</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about">About Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

When I clicked in to "Start Bootstrap" text, the menu will be show but the avatar also push down the menu. See the following image
[image: https://i.imgur.com/OhILgEc.png]

But I want it will look like this
[image]

I tried to bring "avatar" div on the collapse but when see on PC, It will be
[image]

Sorry again because I can't post image. It says "You need as least 10 reputation to post images"

Any one has a solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

Apply the css part if not

```
.avatar-image {
    background-image: url('https://avatars.servers.getgo.com/2205256774854474505_medium.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: May be your css conflict with other css as you applied for other component

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you mean a bit

Comment: May be your other css conflict with this part of navbar. May be for same class name

Answer (score 0):

Add a `float: right` property in `.avatar-image` class.

```css
.avatar-image {
    float: right;
    background-image: url('https://avatars.servers.getgo.com/2205256774854474505_medium.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sb-navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="ml-1">Start Bootstrap</span>
    </a>
    <div class="avatar-image">
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto pt-3 pt-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/item">Product</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about">About Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you! You solve that problem, but the image will turn into square image, how to make it rounded?

Comment: I didn't recognize that part. I've edited my post.

Comment: Aww, I mean this will be the result on pc
https://i.imgur.com/lHg5tsw.png
not like the image on post. Sorry my bad english